# If there was an error in a Lua program, will that error be at the top of the stack?

Tags: c, lua, stack

I have been looking through the Lua source code, and I think that is how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua and C use a stack to exchange arguments. Many script languages use this way to communicate with C program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Programming In Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html) is an excellent resource for these sorts of questions.